# Jquery Math and monetery value

Tags: jquery, math

I have a very specific jquery function I need to write and I'm getting stuck. Here is the code.

```
<input style="width:30px;" type="text" maxlength="200" 
       class="contact" value="" id="cost" name="cost"> 
equivlent of <span id="displayValue"></span>
```

What I need is when somebody enters a value into the input field it times that value by 50p (UK currency) and outputs the numeric value in the span.

i.e. if somebody enters '20' in the input box I get the results £10:00

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

James

Comment: can you show your current javascript that will help us

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following:

- jQuery's [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method to get the value of the `<input>`
- the native JavaScript method [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to help with the math
- jQuery's [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text) method to set the text of the `<span>`.

If you post your JavaScript, we could help point out if there are any problems with it, but since you just asked to be pointed in the right direction, I'll leave the exact usage of the above up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener for key pressed, which converts the field value to a float, and multiply it by 0.5 :

```
$("#cost").keypress(
   function(){
     var result = 0.5 * parseFloat(this.value);
     // do something with the result
   }
);
```